# Unix shell script to copy directories

Tags: shell, unix

Need a unix shell script to remotely copy directories listed in a file to a remote host. Basically, HostA has the directories and I need them to be copied to remote host HostB. The file with the list of directories is in HostA. The file, list.txt, has the following directories listed:

```
/var/tmp/a
/var/tmp/b
/var/tmp/c
/var/tmp/d
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

1. cat list.txt
2. send that list over to scp. Use xargs, awk.

Then,

```
scp username1@source_host:directory1/filename1 username2@destination_host:directory2/filename2
```